# MongoDB & PyMongo: how to store a set / list?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Apparently it is not possible and the best advice I found so far is to use dict but this is not what I want. Is there still a way to store a set / list in MongoDB?

Comment: You can't store a set but you can store lists. What makes you think you can't?

Comment: I think I got the question now. You can't store lists directly but have to 'store' them in a dict. So your document will always look like something like this: {_id: ObjectId("..."), list: [...]}

Answer (score 2):

With mongo you have to pass a json (which in python we can essentially think of as a dict) in order to do anything really, so say you want to add a list or set of numbers to the `hamburgers` field in your collection, you would prepare it as follows:

`db.your_collection.update({'$push': {'hamburgers': {$each: [1, 2, 3, 4]}}})`

if it's a set, you cant convert it to a list

`db.your_collection.update({'$push': {'hamburgers': {$each: list({1, 2, 3, 4})}}})`

Comment: Also if you want to append to a list, you can try: `db.your_collection.update_one({ 'filter_name' : 'filter_value'},{'$addToSet' : {'list_name' : 'item_to_add'}})` using pymongo.